# Printing string that was truncated by Angular filter

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, printing

In my Angular app, I have a built a view with the specific purpose of showing data in a printer-friendly manner.

However, I have also added the option to show more/less text with an Angular `filter` that cuts `strings` to a pre-defined number of characters and lets the user see the rest by clicking a button, like so: `{{elem | cut:!show[$index]:true:max}}`.

Here is the complete filter:

```
angular.module('pear').filter('cut', function () {
    return function (value, enabled, wordwise, max, tail) {

        if (!value) return '';
        max = parseInt(max, 10);
        if (!max) return value;
        if(!enabled) return value;
        if (value.length <= max) return value;

        value = value.toString().substr(0, max);
        if (wordwise) {
            var lastspace = value.lastIndexOf(' ');
            if (lastspace != -1) {
                value = value.substr(0, lastspace);
            }
        }

        return value + (tail || '...');
    };
});
```

And this is how it ends up looking:

[image: Angular filter in action]

Is there a way to disable this `filter` for the print view, or somehow force a css condition with `@media print` that will display the full text?

For reference, this is how I am currently using the filter in my template, in case a different markup approach is needed:

```
<div class="content"> {{elem | cut:!show[$index]:true:max}}
    <span ng-show="!show[$index] && elem.length > max" class="show-more" ng-click="toggleShow($index)">more</span>
    <span ng-show="show[$index]" class="show-more no-print" ng-click="toggleShow($index)">less</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not to add second <span ng-show> to display not-truncated string and assign to it some @media print css?

Comment: @Trike Yes that might be the best, if not the only, approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1g27LL4/3/).

Add the following code to your controller. The logic is: before your print, disable the filter. And re-enable it after printing. Use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to detect whether it is printing.

> Note: be careful about the browser compatibility (IE>=10, Opera>=12.1, etc.)

The advantage of this solution is that: you can control the view not only through CSS. Actually you can **design** your view for printing specifically. Of course, after printing you need to *restore* the previous status.

```
if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            var isPrinting = mql.matches;
            $scope.enabled = !isPrinting;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah! This is much better, I wasn't really enjoying the extra clutter in my html. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `@media print` in my `sass` file, and creating a couple of classes that will help me forcefully hide or show specific elements as I see fit, like so:

```
@media print {
    .no-print, .no-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .force-print, .force-print * {
        display: block !important;
    }
    html, body, .main-content {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I've used them in my template by creating two `<span>` elements, one with the class `.no-print`, which includes the truncated string, and another one with the classes `.force-print` and `hidden`, which includes the element without any filter.

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="no-print">{{elem | cut:!show[$index]:true:max}}</span>
    <span class="hidden force-print">{{elem}}</span>
</div>
```

When printing, `.force-print` will override Bootstrap's `hidden` class, showing an element that is otherwise invisible to the user.